# Most effective way to fill categorical NAs based on string manipulation

Tags: pandas, string, lambda, apply

I have two columns: `age` and `n_age`. `n_age` is a number; `age` is a category of decade. For example, `age` might be `56`, and `n_age` would be `50s`.

I've filled the `NA`s of the `n_age` column with random sampling. I'd like to now use the most efficient method to fill the `age` column. I've used an `apply` with a `lambda`, like so:

```
df['age'].fillna(df['n_age'].apply(lambda x: str(x//10)+'0s'))
```

Thankfully my data set is relatively small, so this didn't take a long time. I imagine that there's a more efficient way of doing this--what is the better way?

Answer (score 0):

No need apply

```
(df['age'].fillna(df['n_age'])//10).mul(10).astype(str)+'s'
```